# Easy and Clean way to allow user to enter array of String in Javafx

Tags: java, arrays, javafx

I am new to java and have been designing a UI however I have gotten stuck when trying to allow the user to enter and edit an array of String in the GUI. The first thing that came to my mind was a method similar to quizlets.

[image: Quizlet Array Entering System]

However, this seems very technically challenging and above my skill level. After doin a couple hours of research I could not find anything on an easy method to enter and edit and an array of String.
Are there any easy ways to do this or other methods of solving a similar problem.

edit: the picture is just a GUI example, I would just like the user to enter a `[String]`

Comment: Did I understand you correctly? At the beginning there's a blank sheet and every click of "+" icon creates a new term-definition pair? You want to store a matrix(term, definition)?

Comment: @notmyf4ulty I think that I made the question a bit more clear sorry

Comment: Editable [`ListView<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html) with a text field that adds new elements to it?

Comment: @James_D Won't a ``TableView`` be more appropriate for that particular case?

Comment: @notmyf4ulty Why? He just has a single list of Strings. What would go in the other columns?

Comment: @James_D I thought that the author had a pair of ``String``s in his mind, but maybe it's just my misinterpretation.

Comment: @notmyf4ulty I just have a list of Strings